# mysql_num_rows causes an error message

Tags: mysql-num-rows

My simplified code is:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM list";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
echo mysql_num_rows($result);
?>
```

I get the following error:
"Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\mysqli_num_rows.php on line 4"

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with that (simplified) code?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd");
mysql_select_db("database", $con);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM list";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
echo mysql_num_rows($result);
?>
```

Comment: Hi, It didn't work ! I get the following error: >Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\mysqli_num_rows.php on line 5

Comment: I managed to get code that works. It goes like this:><?php
require('mysqli_connect.php');
$myEmail= 'aa@a.a';
$q = "SELECT * FROM list WHERE email = '$myEmail'";
$result = @mysqli_query($dbcon, $q);
$num = @mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($num > 0) 
{ 
 echo $num;
}
else
{
 echo 'no record found!';
}
?> Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have a hunch that `$result` is returning `false`, hence the error about a boolean value. This could mean that either the connection or the query is wrong.

Try putting:
`$result = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());`

This hopefully would return an error message telling you what is wrong.

Also another point, you probably should be using mysqli or PDO API as mysql is being depreciated.

Comment: Hi,This code did work for me ! Left to find what differnce is there between 2 codes. ><?php
require('mysqli_connect.php');
$myEmail= 'aa@a.a';
$q = "SELECT * FROM list WHERE email = '$myEmail'";
$result = @mysqli_query($dbcon, $q);
$num = @mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($num > 0) 
{ 
 echo $num;
}
else
{
 echo 'no record found!';
}
?>